# custom dropdown box to submit to session variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

this one has been bugging me for a few days

what i would like to do is on one of my views i would like to get a list of Locations (Entity) and submit the selected location to a session variable so i can show relative data according to the location

i'm unsure how to go about setting this up

any response would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this with Spring, you can get direct access to the HttpSession object and just shove the data right in there.  Your controller method signature would look something like this in Spring 3.0:

```
public ModelAndView someMeaningfulName(@ModelAttribute Location location, HttpSession httpSession) {
  httpSession.setAttribute("location", location);
  // Other method code
}
```

You you have access to the HttpServletRequest object, you can also gain access to the HttpSession from that object as well (request.getSession()).  Just be aware, that the HttpSession object may not be thread safe and that the scope of this object is now tied to the User's session.